# How do i web scrape from airbnb

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I received a dataset on airbnb with this columns:

```
Variable    Definition
id  listing ID
name    name of the listing
host_id host ID
host_name   name of the host
neighbourhood_group region
neighbourhood   sub region
latitude    latitude coordinates
longitude   longitude coordinates
room_type   listing space type
price   (Target) daily rental price in dollars
minimum_nights  amount of nights minimum
number_of_reviews   number of reviews
last_review latest review
reviews_per_month   number of reviews per month
calculated_host_listings_count  amount of listing per host
availability_365    number of days when listing is available for booking
```

If i want to get listing date, how do i do it?
which columns can i use as the element to get the listing date?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/2732"
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
listing_date = soup.find('span', {'class': 'listing-date'}).text
```

i tried this but i have no idea what i am doing, got it from online

Comment: Can you share/add the entire link and screenshot of webpage also highlight the item which you need to extract.

Comment: i not sure exactly which webpage it is, i only know it is airbnb and i want to extract listing date

Comment: Based on the dataset columns you provided, there is no direct column that indicates the listing date of an Airbnb property. The dataset includes details like id, name, host_id, and availability_365, but none of these directly tell you when the listing was first created or made available on Airbnb.